# Starting point to use Trilinos linear algebra packages?

Tags: linear-algebra, fluid-dynamics, petsc, trilinos

I have experience with classical linear algebra packages in C++ like Eigen, Blaze, etc.
I have never wrote my own PetSC back-end solver but I used/modified several of them.

In a new project I would like to use Tpetra with CUDA acceleration (by kokkos?) for a dense linear algebra problem.

The initial version of my code would be just a single node (multi-core CPU + GPU)implementation.

I look at tutorials of Kokkos and Tpetra but couldn't find how to use them together with CUDA and OpenMP support.

Is there any tutorial, sample codes, suggestion to start use them with CUDA.

Comment: Trillions focuses more on sparse problems than dense ones.  Depending on what exactly you're doing, you may be better served by a dedicated dense linear algebra library like SLATE (multi-node CPU+GPU) or maybe MAGMA/cuBLAS/etc (single node GPU).

Comment: Hi @NeilLindquist,

Even tough they have a focus on distributed sparse linear algebra the packages Tpetra/Petsc still handle dense linear algebra too. 

Especially with Kokkos not only GPU also OpenMP paralellization is possible with single source code, I prefer a multi-backend library rather than domain specific one.

Comment: I wasn't trying to say that Trilinos won't work for your application.  Just that, since it's an unusual choice, there may be other options that give better performance and/or more functionality for dense problems.  (The Trilinos developers don't invest as much effort into their dense routines as, e.g., the SLATE developers.)  But, like I said, it's very dependent on what your application is.